# Make an sql group by non commutative

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Hi I have a question for some sql GROUP BY commands.

I have a table which looks like this

```
messages(#id, from_user, to_user, message)
```

If from_user (of id 1) sends a message to to_user (of id 2) it makes this :

| id | from_user | to_user | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | blabla |

Now let's assume we have more data :

| id | from_user | to_user | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | blabla |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | blabla |
| 3 | 9 | 10 | blabla |
| 4 | 11 | 12 | blabla |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | blabla |

In the above table you can see that user 1 sent a message to user 2 AND user 2 sent a message to user 1.

If I want the count of all messages for each "conversation" I guess that I have to do a GROUP BY aggregation like follow :

```
SELECT from_user, to_user, COUNT(*) AS nb_messages
FROM `message`
GROUP BY from_user_id, to_user_id
```

But with this operation it gives :

| from_user | to_user | nb_messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

What I would like is to "merge" the lines where (from_user=1 and to_user=2) and (from_user=2 and to_user=1) so it would give this view :

| from_user | to_user | nb_messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 12 | 1 |

Or even better would be :

| from_user | to_user | nb_messages_sent | nb_messages_received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 11 | 12 | 1 | 0 |

If you have any idea of how to do this, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi @jarlh, I'm using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count by least, greatest conditionally

```
select 
    least(from_user, to_user) from_user, 
    greatest(from_user, to_user) to_user,
    count(case when from_user < to_user then id end) as from_messages,
    count(case when from_user > to_user then id end) as to_messages
from `message`
group by least(from_user, to_user), greatest (from_user, to_user)
```